# memory mapped read from a fie I/O C/C++

Tags: c, io, memory-mapped-files

I'm new in the area of memory mapped and I was wondering if there is any way I can read a text file using memory mapped to a string. I don't really know how to start to write the code.

Comment: C strings end with a 0 byte, which isn't going to be the case with most files. But if you keep track of the length of the memory like with any other array that doesn't use a sentinel value at the end, sure.

Answer (score 5):

The general idea with memory mapped I/O is that you tell the operating system (OS)  *what file* you want, and it (after doing some amount of set-up work) tells you *where that file now is in memory.*

Once that contract is performed, you should be able to copy things to and from that memory in any way you wish (such as with `memcpy`), and it will magically handle the I/O for you.

Detail depends on which OS you're using since the ISO C standard doesn't specify this behaviour - it's therefore OS-specific.

For example, Windows uses a file mapping paradigm shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/memory/file-mapping), while Linux uses [`mmap`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) to allow you to subject a file you've already opened to memory mapping (via its file descriptor).

By way of example, this Linux program, a little voluminous due mainly to its error checking and progress reports, memory maps the `file.txt` file and outputs its content:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// Helper function to minimise error code in main.

static int clean(
    int retVal,     // value to return.
    char *err,      // error/NULL, allows optional %s for strerror(errno).
    int fd,         // fd/-1 to close.
    void *filMem,   // memory/NULL to unmap.
    off_t sz,       // size if unmapping.
    void *locMem    // memory/NULL to free.
) {
    if (err)     printf (err, strerror(errno));
    if (locMem)  free(locMem);
    if (filMem)  munmap(filMem, sz);
    if (fd >= 0) close(fd);
    return retVal;
}

int main(void) {
    int fd = open("file.txt", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0) return clean(-1, "Can't open: %s\n", -1, NULL, 0, NULL);
    printf("File opened okay, fd = %d.\n", fd);

    off_t sz = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
    if (sz == (off_t) -1) return clean(-1, "Can't seek: %s\n", fd, NULL, 0, NULL);
    printf("File size is %ld.\n", sz);

    void *fileArea = mmap(NULL, sz, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (! fileArea) return clean(-1, "Can't map: %s\n", fd, NULL, 0, NULL);
    printf("File mapped to address %p.\n", fileArea);

    char *localArea = calloc(1, sz + 1);
    if (! localArea) return clean(-1, "Can't allocate\n", fd, fileArea, sz, NULL);
    memcpy(localArea, fileArea, sz);
    printf("Data copied to %p, result is [\n%s]\n", localArea, localArea);

    return clean(0, NULL, fd, fileArea, sz, localArea);
}
```

Running that on my local system, the results can be seen from the following transcript:

```
pax$ cat file.txt
...This is the input file content.

pax$ ./testprog
File opened okay, fd = 3.
File size is 35.
File mapped to address 0x7f868a93b000.
Data copied to 0x1756420, result is [
...This is the input file content.
]
```

Comment: `off_t sz = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);`?  If you're already using POSIX `open()`, and `mmap()`, just use `fstat()` on the open file descriptor to get the file size.

Comment: the cleanup funtion is pretty neat. I was learning this stuff and the cleanup code quickly became a nightmare.